# PHP Imagick convert JPG to PNG and remove background works but not perfect

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

Is there a way to combine these two codes and results to create something perfect? Also, I would like to refine the outline of the PNG file so that it is more pleasing to the eye.

**Original file:**

[image]

---

**CODE 1:** This code works perfect when I need to remove the background from a solid image (without having to remove areas within it)

```
<?php

// input_file
$input_file = "100001.jpg";

// $output_file
$output_file = "100001.png";

// Load the image
$imagick = new Imagick(realpath($input_file));

// We replace white background with fuchsia to improve clipping
$imagick->floodFillPaintImage("rgb(255, 0, 255)", 2500, "rgb(255,255,255)", 0 , 0, false);

// We convert fuchsia to transparent
$imagick->paintTransparentImage("rgb(255,0,255)", 0, 10);

// We eliminate empty areas to only leave objects
$imagick->trimImage(0);

// Maximum 500 height but the width can exceed 500 if the original image exceeds 500 somewhere
$imagick->resizeImage(0, 500, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);

// We scale to a maximum of 500 width or height, take the largest measurement and lower it to 500
$imagick->scaleImage(500, 500, true);

// We export as PNG
$imagick->setImageFormat('png');

// Path to save new image
$imagick->writeImage($output_file);

// We clean cache
$imagick->clear();

// We destroy everything
$imagick->destroy();

?>
```

**Output file 1:** (In this case the interior of the hoses is not being removed)

[image]

---

**CODE 2:** This does the right thing by removing the background inside the hoses

```
<?php

// input_file
$input_file = "100001.jpg";

// $output_file
$output_file = "100001.png";

// Load the image
$imagick = new Imagick(realpath($input_file));

$backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
$fuzzFactor = 0.1;

// Create a copy of the image, and paint all the pixels that
// are the background color to be transparent
$outlineImagick = clone $imagick;
$outlineImagick->transparentPaintImage($backgroundColor, 0, $fuzzFactor * Imagick::getQuantum(), false);

// Copy the input image
$mask = clone $imagick;
// Deactivate the alpha channel if the image has one, as later in the process
// we want the mask alpha to be copied from the colour channel to the src
// alpha channel. If the mask image has an alpha channel, it would be copied
// from that instead of from the colour channel.
$mask->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_DEACTIVATE);
//Convert to gray scale to make life simpler
$mask->transformImageColorSpace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);

// DstOut does a "cookie-cutter" it leaves the shape remaining after the
// outlineImagick image, is cut out of the mask.
$mask->compositeImage($outlineImagick,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTOUT, 0, 0);

// The mask is now black where the objects are in the image and white
// where the background is.
// Negate the image, to have white where the objects are and black for
// the background
$mask->negateImage(false);

$fillPixelHoles = false;

if ($fillPixelHoles == true) {
        // If your image has pixel sized holes in it, you will want to fill them
        // in. This will however also make any acute corners in the image not be
        // transparent.

        // Fill holes - any black pixel that is surrounded by white will become
        // white
    $mask->blurimage(2, 1);
    $mask->whiteThresholdImage("rgb(10, 10, 10)");

        // Thinning - because the previous step made the outline thicker, we
        // attempt to make it thinner by an equivalent amount.
    $mask->blurimage(2, 1);
    $mask->blackThresholdImage("rgb(255, 255, 255)");
}

//Soften the edge of the mask to prevent jaggies on the outline.
$mask->blurimage(2, 2);

// We want the mask to go from full opaque to fully transparent quite quickly to
// avoid having too many semi-transparent pixels. sigmoidalContrastImage does this
// for us. Values to use were determined empirically.
$contrast = 15;
$midpoint = 0.7 * Imagick::getQuantum();
$mask->sigmoidalContrastImage(true, $contrast, $midpoint);

// Copy the mask into the opacity channel of the original image.
// You are probably done here if you just want the background removed.
$imagick->compositeimage($mask,Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);

// Copy the image with the background removed over it.
$imagick->compositeimage($imagick, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

// We eliminate empty areas to only leave objects
$imagick->trimImage(0);

// Maximum 500 height but the width can exceed 500 if the original image exceeds 500 somewhere
$imagick->resizeImage(0, 500, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);

// We export as PNG
$imagick->setImageFormat('png');

// Path to save new image
$imagick->writeImage($output_file);

// We clean cache
$imagick->clear();

// We destroy everything
$imagick->destroy();

?>
```

**Output file 2:** if you pay attention it also erases the logo inside the fan, even on the upper right screw (see images with green background added at the end)

[image]

---

**Added images with green background to notice problems**

**Output file 1:** Does not remove background inside hoses.

[image]

**Output file 2:** Error, remove TT fan logo and fan screw top right

[image]

Comment: I've had a good look for you, there doesn't appear to be a way for Imagick to ignore small areas and only transparent fill the larger ones. It just simply doesn't know what is background and what is a part of the image.

Comment: it will be virtually imposible to do this automagically, definition of the background will vary and there will be a error somewhat

Comment: The output makes sense the fan logo has some white pixels that are pixel similar to the white background this can only be solved manually,same thing for the edges which are not exactly white but transition between black and white

Comment: Also there is something called compression if you are going to do background removal you better have your initial image as png not jpg...if you are curious why then google png vs jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a simple image loader and add dynamic div insertion that can be resized over the image to ignore some x,y on specific area, that zone will be excluded while you're making the image transparent.